# Succesive calls to cProfile/pstats no updating properly

Tags: python

I'm trying to make successive calls of some profiler code however on the second call to the function the update time of the profile file changes but the actual profiler stats stay the same. This isn't the code I'm running but it's as simplified an example I can come up with that shows the same behaviour.

On running, the first time ctrl+c is pressed it shows stats, second time same thing but rather than being fully updated as expected only the time is, and third time program actually quits. If trying, ideally wait at a few seconds between ctrl+c presses.

Adding profiler.enable() after the 8th lines does give full updates between calls however it adds a lot of extra profiler data for things I don't want to be profiling.

Any suggestions for a happy medium where I get full updates but without the extra fluff?

```
import signal, sys, time, cProfile, pstats

call = 0

def sigint_handler(signal, frame):
global call
if call < 2:
    profiler.dump_stats("profile.prof")
    stats = pstats.Stats("profile.prof")
    stats.strip_dirs().sort_stats('cumulative').print_stats()
    call += 1
else:
    sys.exit()
def wait():
time.sleep(1)

def main_io_loop():
signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, sigint_handler)
while 1:
    wait()

profiler = cProfile.Profile()
profiler.runctx("main_io_loop()", globals(), locals())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling profiler.dump_stats (implemented in cProfile.py) calls profiler.create_stats, which in turns calls profiler.disable().

You need to call profiler.enable() to make it work again. No, this is not documented.

The following seems to do what you want. Note that I got rid of the intermediate data file since pstats.Stats knows how to get the data from the profiler directly.

```
import signal, sys, time, pstats, cProfile

call = 0

def sigint_handler(signal, frame):
  global call
  if call < 2:
    stats = pstats.Stats(profiler)
    stats.strip_dirs().sort_stats('cumulative').print_stats()
    profiler.enable()
    call += 1
  else:
    sys.exit()

def wait():
  time.sleep(1)

def main_io_loop():
  signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, sigint_handler)
  while 1:
    wait()

profiler = cProfile.Profile()
profiler.runctx("main_io_loop()", globals(), locals())
```

Comment: Thanks, enabling the profiler after print_stats() stops the profiler getting polluted with the "fluff" I mentioned when I was putting enable() before that.

Also thanks for the tip on passing profiler directly to stats. I need the file this time but I'll remember that for the future.

Comment: I didn't understand your comment about fluff the first time I read it. I've not used "enable" before. I wonder if you had embedded the alternative code inline, along with a comment, if that would have made it easier for me to reproduce the fluff.